# Is there a way to print to a printer shared on an Airport Extreme via AirPrint?

Tags: mac, networking, printing, airport, ios

I understand AirPrint is not officially supported for Airport devices, but I'd like to find a way around this. Is there a patch or piece of software I can use to get my Airport Extreme to translate AirPrint requests into something it can use for the printers it shares?

P.S. I was unable to create an AirPrint tag; I suggest this be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Printopia](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/) by Ecamm will enable AirPrint for any printer visible to your Mac, as long as said Mac is running. It’s what I use to print to the old LaserJet I have hooked to my Time Capsule from iOS.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something somehow running on the network but that should work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, that means the printer is wired to the Mac.  Printopia is great, however.  With multiple wifi access points it is the solution to printing, as AirPrint will not work with multiple access points (at least Epson printers won't).